# Triggering template in style is not working after changing template in code

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles, controltemplate

I am trying to switch `ControlTemplate` of Button in Style.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TestProperty}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyCustomTemplate}"/>
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It's working fine until I change button's template in code. For example,

```
myButton.Template = someTemplate;
```

Even this is enought to reproduce a bug:

```
myButton.Template = myButton.Template;
```

By the way the following code will correctly change `myButton` foregound to `Aqua`. It means that trigger is working fine. Its just can not set Template

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TestProperty}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyCustomTemplate}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: have you also set Template on the button itself?

Comment: button had its default template. And without setting `myButton.Template = myButton.Template` trigger works fine.

Comment: If you set myButton.Template directly (as local value) a style value can't override this. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing).

Comment: @LPL Is there any way to manipulate control's template both from code and styles. I need this because i'am using MVVM pattern and want my control to trigger its template depending on some properties in ViewModel. From other side i need to attach behavior that changes template to TextBox and back to allow some editing options.

Comment: why are you setting the template in codebehind...i wanted to know on what condition you are changing it in codebehind..in order to make it work.. you will have to do that using triggers

Comment: If you are using MVVM I'm pretty sure there is no reason to manipulate templates from code. I would say try to use Triggers and DataTemplate.DataType ([sample here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/different_datatemplates_for_different_types.aspx)) only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments for the question, using MVVM and changing controls in code behind is a bad idea.

Your behavior should define a boolean attached property, let's call it `IsInEditMode`. Then, instead of setting the template directly, set the value of the attached property to `true`. In your styles/templates add triggers to change templates (or set visibility for parts of the template) depending on the value of `IsInEditMode`.

This way you'll have ability to react to all combinations of properties (`IsInEditMode && TestProperty`; `IsInEditMode && !TestProperty`; etc...)

Also, you'll be able to use the behavior on other controls.